# Canon MG5300 printer will not print after reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, 20.04

First, be patient with me as I am new to Ubuntu. Had Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my computer and my printer worked no problem. Upgraded to 20.04 and still had no problems until I had to reinstall 20.04. In the first installation home directory was all one, now I have switched to home on a separate partition (don't think that would be part of the problem but I'm trying to give you as much info as I can). I went into Ubuntu wiki "debugging printing problems" and ran through the terminal commands that were there. Below is the output from my terminal session.

```
james@asus-main:~$ lpstat -p -d  
printer Canon_MG5300_series is idle.  enabled since Wed 06 May 2020 08:40:43 PM  
no system default destination
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ lpoptions -d printer  
lpoptions: Unknown printer or class.
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ lsmod | grep usb  
usblp                  24576  0  
usb_storage            77824  2 uas,ums_realtek  
usbhid                 57344  0  
hid                   131072  2 usbhid,hid_generic
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog  
May  6 20:54:12 asus-main systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...    
May  6 20:54:12 asus-main PackageKit: daemon start  
May  6 20:54:12 asus-main dbus-daemon[782]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'  
May  6 20:54:12 asus-main systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.  
May  6 20:54:12 asus-main PackageKit: resolve transaction /29_cbcedcda from uid 1000 finished with success after 356ms  
May  6 20:54:39 asus-main PackageKit: resolve transaction /30_caccbeda from uid 1000 finished with success after 352ms  
May  6 20:55:53 asus-main PackageKit: resolve transaction /31_edddebed from uid 1000 finished with success after 354ms  
May  6 20:55:53 asus-main PackageKit: get-details transaction /32_cbdbcbcd from uid 1000 finished with success after 358ms  
May  6 20:57:35 asus-main snapd[798]: api.go:985: Installing snap "libreoffice" revision unset  
May  6 20:57:45 asus-main systemd[1727]: gnome-launched-gnome-control-center.desktop-6086.scope: Succeeded.
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.  
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main udev-configure-printer: add usb-001-008  
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1  
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main udev-configure-printer: Device already handled  
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-008.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
May  6 21:00:10 asus-main systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-008.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  6 21:00:25 asus-main systemd-resolved[770]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.  
May  6 21:00:26 asus-main systemd-resolved[770]: message repeated 2 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]  
May  6 21:00:26 asus-main colord[870]: failed to get session [pid 3480]: No data available  
May  6 21:00:57 asus-main PackageKit: daemon quit
May  6 21:00:57 asus-main systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.  
^C
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ tail -f /var/log/syslog  
May  6 21:01:43 asus-main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)  
May  6 21:01:43 asus-main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)  
May  6 21:01:43 asus-main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)  
May  6 21:01:43 asus-main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   74.48  1280 1336 1472 1664  720 721 724 746 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz e)  
May  6 21:01:43 asus-main /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1813]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   71.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.3 kHz e)  
May  6 21:01:45 asus-main ModemManager[885]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/0000:03:00.0': not supported by any plugin  
May  6 21:01:47 asus-main dbus-daemon[1740]: apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="session" path="/org/gtk/Notifications" interface="org.gtk.Notifications"   member="AddNotification" mask="send" name="org.gtk.Notifications" pid=2246 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=2068 peer_label="unconfined"
May  6 21:01:47 asus-main systemd[1727]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.  
May  6 21:02:07 asus-main tracker-store[6792]: OK  
May  6 21:02:07 asus-main systemd[1727]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.  
^C
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ lsusb  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader  
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04a9:1754 Canon, Inc. PIXMA MG5300 Series  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4de2 Primax Electronics, Ltd USB Optical Mouse  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4e26 Primax Electronics, Ltd Wired USB Keyboard  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ ls -l /dev/usb/lp* /dev/bus/usb/*/*  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189,   0 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/001/001  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189,   3 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/001/004  
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root lp   189,   7 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/001/008  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 128 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/002/001  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 256 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/003/001  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 257 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/003/002  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 258 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/003/003  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 384 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/004/001  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 512 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/005/001  
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 640 May  6 21:01 /dev/bus/usb/006/001  
crw-rw----  1 root lp   180,   0 May  6 21:01 /dev/usb/lp0
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp0  
[sudo] password for james:   
GET_DEVICE_ID string:  
MFG:Canon;CMD:BJL,BJRaster3,BSCCe,NCCe,IVEC,IVECPLI;SOJ:BJNP2,BJNPe;MDL:MG5300   series;CLS:PRINTER;DES:Canon MG5300   series;VER:2.030;STA:10;FSI:03;HRI:2;MSI:BOFF,DAT,E3,HFSF,JOFF,K21000700;PDR:B;PSE:ACFC35272;
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ sudo usb_printerid /dev/usb/lp1  
Error: No such file or directory: can't open '/dev/usb/lp1'
```

```
james@asus-main:~$ lpinfo -v  
network beh  
file cups-brf:/  
network socket  
network lpd  
network ipp  
network http  
network https  
direct hp  
network ipps  
direct usb://Canon/MG5300%20series?serial=2B2112&interface=1  
direct hpfax  
network dnssd://Canon%20MG5300%20series._printer._tcp.local/  
james@asus-main:~$
```

As I'm typing this, my printer has been trying to print a document for the last 60 min. The printer will not print a test page. The printer is obviously being seen by the system. There could be a problem with the printer; before I re-arranged my work station the printer was able to use the bottom tray. But after moving the printer around and flipping it on its side to connect the cable it began making weird clicking noises when I tried to print from the bottom tray. Had to use the back drop in for the paper, it did work until I reinstalled 20.04 and set the home on a different partition. ?????

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem on a Pixma MP230 like this:

1. Remove `ippusbxd`:  (run `sudo apt remove ippusbxd` in terminal)
2. Delete and reinstall the printer using the GUI printer utility
3. Print a test page

This worked for me after hours of troubleshooting, I hope it works for you as well!

You might also want to read these related questions where more knowledgeable people than me explain how all printers now are "network printers" or something like that. Apparently removing `ippusbxd` isn't the most elegant solution, but as long as it works I'm happy :-)

- [Getting HP DeskJet 3700 working with Xubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264255/getting-hp-deskjet-3700-working-with-xubuntu-20-04)
- [Canon PIXMA MP230 doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248948/canon-pixma-mp230-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-20-04)