# Printer Problems in Ubuntu 20.04 with Samsung Xpress C410 printer

Tags: printing, samsung

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and it went smoothly. The only problem is with printing. The printer installation went fine - selected the driver etc. All good.

However, when I actually send something to the printer it doesn't print. I get the notification that the document is being printed and then that printing has been completed. The printer makes an audible click and the green light flashes briefly, as if it's received the document. But nothing prints!

The printer is working fine with a windows laptop, and it worked fine with Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not very tech-savvy, so responses in words of one syllable appreciated.

Comment: I would not say that installation went fine unless you have successfully been able to use the device, which it seems like you haven't ever gotten it to print.  Are you using the Linux driver provided by HP? https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-c410-color-laser-printer-series/17157201

Comment: Thanks. I've installed the driver following the instructions I found here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2331973. However when I go through the printer config it finds the printer and takes me to the usual list of drivers. Still no printing

Comment: Add a screenshot of Settings---> Printers in the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `ippusbxd`:  (run `sudo apt remove ippusbxd` in terminal)
2. Delete and reinstall the printer using the GUI printer utility
3. Print a test page

This worked for me after hours of troubleshooting, I hope it works for you as well!

You might also want to read these related questions where more knowledgeable people than me explain how all printers now are "network printers" or something like that. Apparently removing `ippusbxd` isn't the most elegant solution, but as long as it works I'm happy :-)

- [Getting HP DeskJet 3700 working with Xubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264255/getting-hp-deskjet-3700-working-with-xubuntu-20-04)
- [Canon PIXMA MP230 doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248948/canon-pixma-mp230-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Thanks - really grateful for the suggestion. Alas it hasn't worked.