# Hp printer not printing correctly after ubuntu 20.04 install

Tags: printing, hp, cups-lpd

I have an Hp printer which was working fine with ubuntu 18.04 through USB cable without installing hplip as I faced problem with it previously.

When printing through wireless the documents were shifted upwards, but was printed perfectly using USB with certain settings in evince.

Now after installing Ubuntu 20.04, documents are shifted upwards also throught USB.

Besides, The printer keeps added and I had more than one printer shown in evince one of which keeps stuck at getting printer information, I also faced many errors like  "No suitable Destination Host found by cups-browsed". I Installed the hplip with no success.

Finally decided to make factory reset to the printer and reinstalled Ubuntu with the printer plugged in. Now only one printer added but still the shifting problem exsits no matter what settings I am using.

Sorry for the long question, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Installing hplip didn't solve the problem at all, actually I was printing without it being installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Comment: I've already installed hplip before reinstalling Ubuntu again and it didn't solve the problem at all, actually I was printing fine without it on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This is not specific to HP printers. It happened to me with both a Brother and an Epson after I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. I could fix it by removing ippusbxd after reading @rinre 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `ippusbxd`:  (run `sudo apt remove ippusbxd` in terminal)
2. Delete and reinstall the printer using the GUI printer utility
3. Print a test page

This worked for me after hours of troubleshooting, I hope it works for you as well!

You might also want to read these related questions where more knowledgeable people than me explain how all printers now are "network printers" or something like that. Apparently removing `ippusbxd` isn't the most elegant solution, but as long as it works I'm happy :-)

- [Getting HP DeskJet 3700 working with Xubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264255/getting-hp-deskjet-3700-working-with-xubuntu-20-04)
- [Canon PIXMA MP230 doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248948/canon-pixma-mp230-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Thank you for this. In my case my printers began to work right after I removed ippusbxd, no other steps were needed.

Comment: Five months later the printer stopped working again. I can only print the test page and basic text only content. Repeated the steps that worked before, but are not effective now.

Comment: Sorry to hear that @AlejandroVD
I am in the middle of a move and haven't set up the printer in my new home yet, so it will be interesting to see if it will work now...

Answer (score 0):

## Update

I have now switched over to using [ghostscript-printer-app](https://snapcraft.io/ghostscript-printer-app) from snap store.

Following the instruction in their github repo:

```
sudo snap install ghostscript-printer-app --edge
```

Go to http://localhost:8000/ and specify your printer device and model. It worked right out of the box for me!

## Old Solution

I faced the same problem as you did, but in my case I tried to install hplip and got "Device Communication Error" when printing. Below is my approach in case anyone needs it:

### 1. Remove ippusbxd as suggested by @rinre

```
sudo apt remove ippusbxd
```

### 2. Check the presence of hplip package and its dependencies

```
dpkg --list | grep .*hplip.*
```

### 3. Purge hplip and all of its dependencies

```
sudo apt purge hplip*
```

### 4. Remove partially installed hplip just in case

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/.*hplip.*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
```

### 5. Restart the printer

1. Turn off (or unplug) and turn on again (plugin)
2. Go to Ubuntu's **Settings** > **Printers** > **Add printers**
3. Test your printer